# Using thread with sort algorithm

Tags: c++, multithreading, sorting

I'm trying to use `thread` with my two functions. In the first one , I'm trying to write in a `.txt` file some information , and also using `vec.push_back(str);` in order to fill my `vector`, and then sort my recording information in another function `SortVec()` and show it on the console.

If I don't use `thread` and `mutex`, I mean ,if I just call those functions in the `main`, everything works fine without mistakes. But if I would like to use `thread` and `mutex` in order to write some information, then sort it, and again write and sort, and stop it, when I want , it fails.

I only see on my console `Recording()` function without `SortVec()`. It means , `std::thread Sort(&STring::SortVec, &w);` doesn't woke up.

Can you help me with that? What do I do wrong with that? Because I'm lost a little bit, don't get it , why it goes like this.

**STring.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

class STring
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::mutex mtx;
public:

    STring(){}
    void Recording();
    void SortVec();

};
```

**STring.cpp**:

```
#include "STring.h"

void STring::Recording()
{
    while (1)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        std::string fileName;
        std::string str;
        std::ofstream out("tt1.txt", std::ios_base::app);


        std::cout << "Input smth: ";
        while (std::cin >> str)
        {
            out << str;
            vec.push_back(str);
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    }

}

void STring::SortVec()
{
    while (1) 
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    //  std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter_vec;
        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());


        for (auto i : vec)
        {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    }

}
```

and **Source.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "STring.h"
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    STring w;

    std::thread Write(&STring::Recording,&w);
    std::thread Sort(&STring::SortVec, &w);

    Sort.join();
    Write.join();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In my opinion, what I'm doing wrong is `uncorrect using time` between two functions.

I'd like to show ,what I see on my console.

[image]

Comment: You are putting a thread to sleep while holding a mutex! That's just wrong.... Again... Just a nitpick: `while (1){ ..... }` without any *normal* exit path doesn't seem nice...

Comment: @WhiZTiM        I think,  `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` can help me with nornal time exit, no? How should I do it correctly?

Comment: @WhiZTiM               I got, that I let a thread to sleep, and only the 1st function works, but how shoul I do in order to all two functions work?

Comment: your program has more issues than I comment on here...

Comment: Have you considered the parallel version of [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) (available since C++17).

Comment: What is the condition for this loop `while (std::cin >> str)` to stop?

Comment: @so61pi        it's "CTRL+Z" for exit

Comment: @WhiZTiM        yes, I understood it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct way to use a `std::lock_guard` in your case is:

```
void STring::Recording()
{
    while (1)
    {
        // use curly braces to create a nested scope
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            //
            // your code here...
            //
            // lock_guard releases the lock when it goes out of scope.
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    }
}
```

You probably have other issues. For example, your first `join()` will just block forever.

Comment: @Blastfurmace   yeah, thanks for that. And yes, my  first `join()` has blocked. Is there  some varinats to wake up it or I should use find another variants like *condititon_variables*?

Comment: @X21 You could try something as simple as a `std::atomic<bool>` to signal "please finish" to the thread(s).